# Non-Dimensionalise This Equation

Tags: dimensional-analysis

I'm first to find the units of all model parameters and subsequently non-dimensionalise the equation. We're given that $y$ and $t$ have units of time whilst $c$ has units of length (with $c$ taken to be a model parameter and $e^x=exp(x)$). The equation is:

$$ y + b{e^{\gamma t}}=c $$

I understand that to begin with I should re-write the two variables $y$ and $t$ as, say:$$y=y^*y'$$$$t=Tt'$$ Beyond this I don't really know what I should do, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have $y$ a time and $c$ a length unless there is a multiplicative constant to fix that.  The units on all terms that are added or subtracted need to be the same.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing which is why I didn't seem to be getting anywhere, my lecturer had said something along lines of "oh just take $c$ to be anything, say a length" but maybe he was referring to the previous question. Say I take $c$ to have some arbitrary unit, will the question work or does $c$ need to have a pre-defined unit consistent with the equation?

Comment: If $y$ is time, then $b$ and  $c$ needs to be time as well.  They don't have to match $t$.  You could also have $y,b,c$ all be length, for example.  You need $\gamma$ to have the inverse units of $t$ so the exponential is applied to something dimensionless.  Then to make it dimensionless, divide by something of the same unit as $y$